# Is it bad to link internal URL with http?

Tags: seo, domains, url, hyperlink, relative-urls

I have couple of domains. One in the singular form and other in the plural. The singular one has more traffic and plural one is new and has a chance of getting visitors on the homepage.

Both the domains are for same website. To prevent website from getting duplicate content penalty I tried to redirect the plural domain to singular domain but it had some negative impact.

Now I want to host both the domains on the same site but linking only to the singular domain.

Is it bad to have internal links as `http://example.com/folder/page` instead of `/folder/page`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to redirect the plural domain to singular domain but it had some negative impact.

What "negative impact"?

What you are proposing (linking to just one domain) is essentially the same thing, but in a roundabout sort of way.

> Is it bad...

Bad for who? It's harder to maintain (depending on how you manage your links). Costs a few more bytes (insignificant, unless you have an enormous number of links). Marginally harder for someone to copy your site. Search engines don't care.

> ... and plural one is new and has a chance of getting visitors on the homepage.

To clarify, the "singular" and "plural" domains host *exactly* the same content?

However, it sounds like you should be redirecting one domain to the other?

Comment: I tried redirecting the domain but the traffic reduced drastically. So I have to park it.

Comment: "Search engines don't care". That's what I was asking for.

Comment: "Is it bad to have internal links [such] as http://example.com/folder/page instead of /folder/page?" No it is the same. The first type is called an 'absolute' link and the second is called a 'relative' link. As long as the relative link is relative to where you are calling it from, it is fine.